# Can sublimation explain why flavored water can suddenly freeze when being taken out of a freezer?

Tags: thermodynamics, pressure, temperature, vacuum

I've experienced taking a liquid ice bar sealed in plastic and it suddenly is completely frozen. Could this be sublimation?

Comment: Google for "supercooling."

Answer (score 0):

No it isn't. it is possible for a sample of water to be cooled below the freezing point and yet remain liquid, if there are no suitable nucleation sites to trigger the phase change. then if the supercooled water is perturbed even very slightly it will freeze solid in an instant.

Note that it is common for the water droplets in a freezing-cold cloud to remain liquid until perturbed by the passage of an airplane wing, whereupon the water freezes and sticks to the wing to form an ice layer that grows thicker and thicker as the plane traverses the cloud. the mass of ice and the effect it has on airflow over the wing will eventually overload the plane and cause it to crash.

Airplanes certified for flying in icing conditions like this have devices on them which either pop the ice loose from the wings, heat it so it melts, or melt it off with alcohol.

Comment: I really appreciate your answer. I was thinking about freeze drying ice cream and that without something like a heat source (or maybe a little bit of a shake) the ice cream would just be a pile of goop...That made me think of the freezer pop that only turns to ice as you snap it.

Comment: @SolomonSlow slow, will edit.